# Cassandra creates tens of thousands hd files for a column family

Tags: cassandra

I have a column family with a lot of data. Tens of millions keys with small data items, and it's growing.

I've noticed cassandra created about 170k files called like this:

```
my_col_family-hd-702036-Data.db
my_col_family-hd-702036-Index.db
my_col_family-hd-702036-Digest.db
my_col_family-hd-702036-Statistics.db
my_col_family-hd-702036-Filter.db
```

They only differ by the number in the file name.

When I re-start cassandra it needs about an hour to get up, the log says:

```
 INFO 09:26:34,649 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/foo/my_col_family-hd-805240 (5243383 bytes)
 INFO 09:26:34,649 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/foo/my_col_family-hd-731915 (5242896 bytes)
 INFO 09:26:34,714 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/foo/my_col_family-hd-797692 (5243454 bytes)
 INFO 09:26:34,753 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/foo/my_col_family-hd-688013 (5243541 bytes)
```

It goes like this for about an hour until it reads all the 170k files

I wanted to ask if this is normal? Why does it create so many small files, 5 MB each and then read all of them on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of files because you are using an old version of Cassandra which uses a default file size of 5mb for Leveled compaction. Further testing has shown that ~160mb is a more optimal file size for this particular compaction strategy. I would recommend switching to the larger size asap.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5727

As to checking for all of them on startup, it isn't actually reading them all. Cassandra is just opening file handles so that it can access data from the files during reads from the database. This is necessary and normal.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I change the default file size? I can't find this in cassandra.yaml

Comment: Not in the yaml, it's part of table level compaction strategy options.